# Change interval depending on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a countdown clock and I'm trying to get it to have different intervals depending on its value, like first third is a month second third is a week and the last part is a day, how can I do it? Now the interval is always a second,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//charttimmer
$(".second").knob();
setUpClock();


$(function(){
  $( "#timer" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler );

  function tapHandler( event ){
  tearDownClock();
  if(!interval){
  setUpClock();
   }
  }
  });
});

function clock(){
var secHtml = $(".second");
var sec = secHtml.val();

if(sec <= 5){
    sec=100
}
else{
    sec--;
}


if(sec-1>=0){
    secHtml.val(sec-1);
    secHtml.change();
}
else{
    tearDownClock();
}

}
function setUpClock(){
interval = setInterval(clock,1000);
}
function tearDownClock(){
window.clearInterval(interval);
interval=null;
}
function setMyOwnVal(){
$(".second").val("20");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaU35/

Answer (score 0):

```
function setUpClock( newInterval ){
    interval = setInterval(clock, newInterval);
}
```

Comment: were should i put this?

Comment: Replace your function with this one.

Comment: the interval function

Comment: were do I send in the new interval

Comment: sorry, im kind of new to this, I need like a if else, have you seen the fiddle,, i really am in need of help and are very thankful for everything

Comment: like if sec < 500 have this interval else have this

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking.

Comment: I want the clock to go at one speed during one half and a other speed during the other half

Comment: You would put your logic into your clock function

Comment: hmm, how?? like if( sec == 100){ sec == sec/2 setUpclock(sec) }

Comment: still doesn't work it just gets quicker, can't seem to edit the value/time ratio

Comment: should i try with a timeout in every step,

Comment: No that will complicate things.

Comment: then how can i do it, can't I just say like between 1000 and 500 a sec is halv a sec